# How to make the Center item size more than the other items in iCarousel using linear type

Tags: ios, icarousel

I am using `iCarousel` with

```
_wrap = YES;
_carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
```

I want the `Centre view` to be big in size than the other items while `scrolling`.
Do any one know How to achieve this?

I want the views to look some thing like this using iCarousel:

http://maniacdev.com/2013/10/nice-easy-to-set-up-open-source-ios-carousel-view-component

Comment: in viewForItemAtIndex: check if index == selected index, then do what you want

Comment: I want the item in the center to be big in size not a single item to be big.

Comment: you can get current item index by carousel.currentItemIndex! then you can set size